# Wordpress Creating Empty database

Tags: windows-8, apache-http-server, database, wamp, wordpress

WordPress is creating an empty database, there is a database but with out any values.

I am on local WAMP Server 2.4 (PHP 5.4) Windows 8 Wordpress 3.6 (also tried 3.5.1)

WAMP Apache is Giving some errors I am pasting few lines here:

**access.log:**

```
"GET /test_3/wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.min.css?ver=3.6 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
"GET /phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?db=db_test_3&token=4bb71407ccf91fc27d3c8338186ee369&db=db_test_3&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&menuHashes=572d5b14-cb7c7ed1-ada592ed-4fce1948&_nocache=1376960501429607598 HTTP/1.1" 200 40875
```

**apache_error.log**

```
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7864:tid 468] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6540
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6540:tid 344] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7864:tid 468] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
```

Past-History: I have changed port to `:8080` because windows 8 was already using port `:80`

Comment: How did you change to port 8080 and where did you set this?

Comment: Along these lines in httpd.conf

#Listen 12.34.56.78:90
Listen 8080
#Listen 0.0.0.0:8080

Looking at it i changed it in to:

#Listen 12.34.56.78:90
#Listen 8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080

And wola database is receiving values now :) but after stetting up wordpress i am receiving this error:
"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Comment: check your wpconfig.php database settings - at some point your settings don't match - plus with phpMyAdmin: check for correct table prefixes, wp_usermeta: wp_capabilities should be a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";} plus wp_user_level 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! -- i might have messed this up while changing port.

### In httpd.conf -- i had this:

```
Listen 8080
#Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
```

### Simply changed it to this:

```
#Listen 8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Database was receiving values but word-press started giving this error on login attempt

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page
```

So i simply went to database and gave my user administrator privileges! ([From here](http://www.dnawebagency.com/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database) i followed the instruction under heading "Editing the wp_usermeta table")

Comment: @Jason Aller I fixed the solution a long time ago and posted answer on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325531/wordpress-creating-empty-database). Forgot to add it here as well.